# Npm audit fix --force does apply its own recommendations

Tags: javascript, npm

there are plenty of similar questions but they have not helped me at all.

I try to get rid off critical vulnerabilities. I have run `npm update`, `npm audit fix` and `npm audit fix --force` many times but it is stalled. I see the same warnings again though the out says it is a fixable trouble. Is there a way to finish it?

```
>npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating update to 0.7.4,which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
npm WARN deprecated set-value@0.4.3: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.

assign-deep  <1.0.1
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1014
fix available via `npm audit fix`

set-value  <=2.0.0 || 3.0.0
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1012
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install update@0.4.2, which is a breaking change
```

Update: I can see too much various versions (even 0.2) of `set-value` in `package.json`. I have set all occurences with the version <= 2.0 to 2.0.1. Tests passed through.

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared your package.json, or at least the dependencies and devDependencies entries.

Comment: Here is the revision I had the trouble: https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/tree/d4e931ab90a8e5db6fb723edb3ca2ecad8636c2b/backend
I have gave up afterwards and updated all insecure dependencies manually in the lock file (later commits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Try `npm uninstall update`.

Using the `package.json` in the [repo that you linked to](https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/tree/d4e931ab90a8e5db6fb723edb3ca2ecad8636c2b/backend) and npm@7, running `npm install` and then `npm audit` reported:

```
46 vulnerabilities (3 low, 11 moderate, 32 high)
```

Running `npm audit fix` didn't change that, which is indeed irksome, but also [a known issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3472).

Running `npm audit fix --force` actually somehow made things *worse*:

```
55 vulnerabilities (9 low, 10 moderate, 36 high)
```

So I started over again with your `package.json` and ran `npm install` and `npm audit` again. The output for `npm audit` includes this:

```
set-value  <=2.0.0 || 3.0.0
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1012
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install update@0.7.4, which is a breaking change
```

So it wants to update the `update` module to version 0.7.4, which is the latest version. I did that manually like this:

```
npm uninstall update && npm install update
```

That got the same result (an increase in vulnerabilities) as `npm audit fix --force` but I did notice that after uninstalling `update`, 0 vulnerabilities were reported.

```
$ npm uninstall update

removed 584 packages, and audited 870 packages in 4s

56 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
$
```

Looking at [the npm page for update](https://www.npmjs.com/package/update), it hasn't been updated itself in 5 years. So maybe replacing that package with something else is your best option here.

Back to your `package.json`, the `update` package is in your `dependencies` which seems wrong as it seems to be a command-line tool. A quick scan of the repo seems to indicate it's not actually used anywhere.

So I'm going to posit that the best solution is `npm uninstall update`.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking a long time, why I included this dependency a year ago. A commit message was to fix some dependency security issue :-) I had the same feeling that npm audit does not helps but made it worse. My resolution was the same - to remove the update package (so stupid package name, try to google it) and manually resolve other dependencies. Thanks for realizing that it was not my fault.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I thought I was going crazy lol.